# CakePHP: Porque o Model não está sendo carregado corretamente?

Tags: php, cakephp, mvc

```
Model: CategoriaBanner
Controller: CategoriasBannersController
```

Uma coisa esta me tirando o sono:
Ao tentar usar `create();` ele dá erro de objeto ao tentar usar no que seria o Model correspondente:

```
$this->CategoriaBanner->create();
```

> Erro: Call to a member function create() on a non-object   File:
>   /meu/path/para/projeto/app/Controller/CategoriasBannersController.php 
>   Line: 8

Já tentei adicionar `public $uses = 'CategoriaBanner';` mas não obtive sucesso. O que poderia ser?
Obs.: Estou usando o *CakePtbr* para solucionar os *inflections*, e não pretendo resolver com *loadModel*, pois quero usar pela convenção.

Comment: Seria interessante ver o código do seu controller.

Comment: Sua declaração do $uses está errada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo visto, a sua solução para os *inflections* não está funcionando, senão o `$uses` nem seria necessário. Sua tentativa com `$uses` foi incorreta, porque o valor dessa propriedade precisa ser uma array. Tente assim:

```
public $uses = array('CategoriaBanner');
```